# Excel VBA Object Required ERROR

Tags: excel, vba

I have two lines of code that seems extremely easy, but excel keeps giving me this Compile error telling me that object is required?

So basically I want to get the current time, and replace the spaces with underscores so I can use this string as the name of my log fime.

```
Dim name As String

'EXCEL GIVE ME compile error: object required
name = Replace(FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LONGTIME), " ", "_")
```

What's wrong?!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke Now as it is not a variable but a procedure

```
var now = str(Now());
name = Replace(FormatDateTime(now, DateFormat.LONGTIME), " ", "_")
```

should fix it

Comment: Your suggestion throws the same error as initial Q. See the answer of @SoulDZIN - it works.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing DateFormat.LONGTIME to 'vbLongTime' works for me.

```
name = Replace(FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime), " ", "_")
```